# CakePHP doesn't set any cookies and session after changing server

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies

I have an application based on CakePHP version 3.2.10. I'm totally new in CakePHP so sorry if it is a banal problem. In my application I use CSRF component and Auth component configured in this way:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize'=> 'Controller',
            'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                            'fields' => [
                                    'username' => 'email',
                                    'password' => 'password'
                            ],
                            'scope' => [
                                    'Users.active' => 1,
                            ]
                    ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'logoutAction' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'logout'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Pages',
                    'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => '/', // $this->referer()
    ]);
```

and login action like

```
public function login()
{
    $this->set('title', 'Logowanie');
    $this->set('bodyclass', 'main-page');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            if($user['blocked'] == 0) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                if ($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin')
                    return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Admin', 'action' => 'index']);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            else{
                $this->Flash->error('Konto zostało zablokowane przez administratora serwisu. Skontaktuj się z Biurem Obsługi.');
            }
        } else $this->Flash->error('Błędne dane logowania. Spróbuj ponownie.');
    }
}
```

Now the problem:

Few days ago I changed server where application is running, and after changing it logging in stopped working. After clicking login there is a message CSRF Token cookie is missing. To test if the component is the problem i disabled csrf and try again then white screen appears and nothing happen if i refresh page i'm not logged in. I checked the working version and not working version and realized that Cake not store any cookies on new server, while on old there is everything ok and cookies are set.

After few researches i found out that not only cookies not work but all sessions. I try to dump $_SEESION but it shows something only right after calling $this->Auth->setUser($user), and nowhere else. So i look through some solutions and find that there is a setting in  config/app.php to set up the session:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
],
```

And read that when set in that way the session is stored in default php dir. So i changed it to cake(even make a dir sessions in tmp folder and added 777 permissions). But the problem was not solved. I have no idea why it not work. I tried setting cookiePath and other settings i Session config, but it still not work.

I think that this may be the server problem(permissions). So few words about servers: Old server where everything was working was my private server(i have full access), new server(or maybe virtual server/host) is on one of hosting companies(home.pl) where i have almost no privileges to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow these steps:

```
//For Set
var $var = array('Cookie');

//For Write
$this->Cookie->write('YOUR DESIRED NAME', cookieData, $expires = null);

//For Read
$this->Cookie->read('YOUR DESIRED NAME');
```

Comment: I don't store any cookies by myself, so these steps are not needed. To login i use default cakephp auth system. And any cookies are not set from cakePHP.

Comment: So it is better for you to show us some code so we can resolve your issued.

Comment: I don't even know when in code my problem lies, and what code to put. But ok. I added login action code where the problem seems to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Conroller code should be in `src/Controller/AppController.php` for below points

1) have you loaded cookie component properly in `initialize()` or `beforeFilter()` method?

2) do you have configured domain and path in your cookie configuration using `$this->Cookie->configKey()`, if Yes, then change domain to new domain or remove domain configuration.

3) delete cache folders for model and persistence from tmp folder

For more information about Cookie refer [Document](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html)

Comment: I don't have any additional configuration for this in my AppController. Is it necessary to initialize this component to make loging in work. As I said it works perfect on other server, without this configuration.

Comment: Other server means with other domain?

Comment: have you deleted cache for models and persistance and other cache file in tmp folder?

Comment: Yes I deleted cache. Yes I changed server and domain.